# Onnxruntime extensions are not installing on Arm Based Processor

Tags: python, onnx, onnxruntime, tf2onnx

**Error when installing onnxruntime-extensions**

- I also tried different versions but everytime got same error

```
error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime-extensions (from versions: none) 
error: no matching distribution found for onnxruntime-extensions
```

**server spec:**

```
Architecture

64-bit (Arm)  # Arm Based processor used in aws ec2 instance

CPU:
Core 16  and 1 thread per core
```

**my enviroment:**

```
python version  3.9

pip install onnxruntime-extensions # but got above error

#===============================================================

#Again deleted enviroment and created new enviroment with

python version  3.7
   
tried to install  pip install onnxruntime-extensions  # but same error arise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has been mentioned on the official GitHub page

> NOTE: most ONNXRuntime-Extensions packages are in active development and most packages require building from source. The package information will be updated here if it is published.

So if you`re working on Windows, try

> pip install --extra-index-url https://aiinfra.pkgs.visualstudio.com/PublicPackages/_packaging/ORT-Nightly/pypi/simple/ onnxruntime-extensions

Or on Linux

> python -m pip install git+https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions.git

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you its worked. ----------------
                         but before installation official  repo say. -------------
The packages are not ready yet, so it could be installed from source. Please make sure the compiler toolkit like gcc(later than g++ 8.0) or clang, and the tool cmake are installed before the following command.

Comment: Could you please show me why-------------- RUN python -m pip install git+https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions.git  ----------- not working in docker file

Comment: There can be multiple problems. Please send me what type of error you get!